# Синхронное добавление точек на карту

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Имеется массив данных о клиентах, которых необходимо занести на карту в виде точек. У каждого клиента обязательно есть адрес, но может быть так, что может оказаться, что нет координат.

Не могу придумать способ для добавления точек и по координатам, если они есть, и по адресу, если координат нет. Дело в том, что функция геокодирования Яндекса работает асинхронно, поэтому на карте отображаются только те точки, которые имеют координаты.

```js
var clients = {
 name: ['Клиент 1', 'Клиент 2', 'Клиент 3', 'Клиент 4', 'Клиент 5', 'Клиент 6', 'Клиент 7'],
  address: [
   'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Херсонская ул, 43 дом, 7 корп',
   'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Лётчика Бабушкина ул, владение 1, строение 27',
    'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Чермянский проезд, 7, 1',
    'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Варварка ул, 6',
    'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Скотопрогонная ул, 29',
    'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Академика Ландау б-р, 9',
    'Российская Федерация, Москва г, Татарская ул, 35'
  ],
  coordinates: [
   ['Нет', 'Нет'],
   [37.666557,55.854249],
    [37.632664,55.888786],
    [37.625729,55.751563],
    ['Нет', 'Нет'],
    [37.553217,55.920381],
    ['Нет', 'Нет']
  ]
};

function init () {
 var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
   center: [37.626, 55.750625],
    zoom: 7,
    controls: []
   }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
 });
  
  for(var i = 0; i < clients.name.length; i++){
   // если нет координат, то определяем их
   if(clients.coordinates[i][0] == 'Нет' && clients.coordinates[i][1] == 'Нет'){
     var coord = null;
      ymaps.geocode(clients.address[i]).then(
    function(res){
         coord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
        },
        function(err){
         console.log('Ошибка геокодирования');
        }
      );
      clients.coordinates[i] = coord;
    }
    // добавляем точки
    var point = new ymaps.Placemark(clients.coordinates[i], {
   balloonContent: clients.name[i]
  }, {
   preset: 'islands#violetDotIcon'
  });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(point);
  }
  myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html, body, #map {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `Promise.all`.
Про промисы можно почитать вот тут http://learn.javascript.ru/promise

```js
var clientsPromises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < clients.name.length; i++) {
    // Функции начнут выпоняться после завершения цикла и в этот моммент
    // будет clients.name.length. Обойти это можно или использованием ES6
    // или созданием новой функции.
    clientsPromises.push(loadClient(i));
}

// Ждем когда для всех клиентов или появятся метки или произойдет ошибка
// геокодирования.
ymaps.vow.Promise.all(clientsPromises)
    .then(function (clients) {
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
    });

function loadClient(clientIndex) {
    // Промис, который резолвится координатами клиента.
    var clientCoordinatesPromise;

    var coordinates = clients.coordinates[clientIndex];

    if (coordinates[0] == 'Нет' && coordinates[1] == 'Нет') {
        // Если координат нет, используем геокодирование.
        clientCoordinatesPromise = ymaps.geocode(clients.address[clientIndex])
            .then(function (res) { return res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(); })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('Ошибка геокодирования');
                // Для этого клиента координаты определить не удалось.
                return null;
            });
    } else {
        // Для унифицикации дальнейшего кода, если координаты уже есть,
        //  создаем зарезолвившийся ими промис.
        clientCoordinatesPromise = ymaps.vow.resolve(coordinates);
    }

    // Подписываемся на получение координат и создаем метку.
    return clientCoordinatesPromise
        .then(function (coordinates) {
            if (!coordinates) {
                // Игнорируем клиентов без координат.
                return null;
            }

            var point = new ymaps.Placemark(coordinates,
                { balloonContent: clients.name[clientIndex] },
                { preset: 'islands#violetDotIcon' });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(point);

            // Можно вернуть дополнительную информацию.
            // Или вообще ничего не возвращать.
            return { point: point, additional: 42 };
        });
}
```

---

Так же советую хранить `clients` в виде массива с объектами, а вместо `'Нет'` для обозначения отсутствия координат использовать `null`:

```
[
  { coordinates: null, name: 'Клиент 1', address: 'улица Пушкина' },
  { coordinates: [42, 42], name: 'Клиент 2', address: 'улица Ленина' },
]
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)